# In Doctrine 2, inheritance without mapping results in unknown columns in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have two classes, one of which was fully developed before the second one. When I came to develop the second one, because it basically was the same but with extra functionality, I extended the class in PHP.

Let's call the parent class ClassA and the child class ClassB (left out getters/setters for brevity):

```
class ClassA
{
    protected $label;
    protected $name;
}

class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    protected $extraField;
}
```

When I came to map it however, I encountered problems. I don't need or want inheritance mapping because I don't want polymorphic querying; both classes are used in different sections of the site and I don't want to return instances of the ClassB when querying ClassA, only to return instances directly of ClassA.

I got the mapping to work by excluding ClassA's attributes from ClassB's mapping (otherwise it complained that the fields were duplicated):

ClassA.dcm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="ClassA" table="a">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

        <field name="label" type="string" nullable="true"/>
        <field name="name" type="text" nullable="true"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

ClassB.dcm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                    http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="ClassB" table="b">
        <field name="extraField" type="string" nullable="true"/>
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

This generated the database tables correctly with all of the required fields. However, when querying it with:

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT b FROM ClassB')->getResult();
```

Then I get an exception thrown because Doctrine is generating this MySQL query by trying to be clever with the inheritance even though I haven't mapped it:

```
SELECT c0_.label AS label0, c0_.name AS name1, c0_.id AS id2, c1_.extraField AS extraField3 FROM b c1_
```

As you can see it's trying to fetch the columns from the A table by specifying an alias for it, when what it should be doing is only fetching from the B table and it complains that the first columns do not exist.

Is there anyway of achieving what I want without having to use Single-Table inheritance or Class-Table inheritance (as I don't want polymorphic queries) or create extra classes (which mapped superclass would require)?

I'm using Doctrine 2.3.3 (latest version) with MySQL and PHP 5.3.